# How to get the absolute raster row / column of rastercell when using ArcObject Raster Cursor?

Tags: arcobjects, raster, c#

When using the ArcObject RasterCursor (see snippet below), how do I get the absolute row / column of the current pixel value?

```
IRasterCursor rasterCursor = raster.CreateCursorEx(null);

do
{
    IPixelBlock3 pixelblock = rasterCursor.PixelBlock as IPixelBlock3;

    Array pixels = (Array)pixelblock.PixelData[rasterBandIndex];

    for (int i = 0; i < pixelblock.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pixelblock.Height; j++)
        {
            // How to get absolute row / column of this pixelvalue
            dynamic pixelValue = pixels.GetValue(i, j);
        }
    }
}
while (rasterCursor.Next());
```

Answer (score 1):

RasterCursor.TopLeft can be used to do this. Don't ask me why it is returning double though.

```
IRasterCursor rasterCursor = raster.CreateCursorEx(null);

do
{
    IPixelBlock3 pixelblock = rasterCursor.PixelBlock as IPixelBlock3;

    Array pixels = (Array)pixelblock.PixelData[rasterBandIndex];

    double x = rasterCursor.TopLeft.X;
    double y = rasterCursor.TopLeft.Y;

    for (int i = 0; i < pixelblock.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pixelblock.Height; j++)
        {
            // This is pixel (int)x + i, (int)y + j of the rasterdataset
            dynamic pixelValue = pixels.GetValue(i, j);
         }
    }
}
while (rasterCursor.Next());
```